# How to make OpenWrt Makefile compile faster?

Tags: linux, compiling, make, openwrt, gnu-make

I have recorded that it took 50 minutes for an initial compilation of the OpenWrt firmware image, assuming all the necessary packages have been installed via `sudo apt-get install`. My BuildRoot Root Dir is `openwrt`.

Subsequently, I found that if I rename the directory above the `openwrt` folder, with a minor change in a file say `wifi.lua` the next **make** (in `openwrt` folder) takes 21 minutes to compile successfully.

However, if I don't rename the directory above the `openwrt` folder, with a similar minor change in the same file, the next **make V=99** takes only 3 minutes to compile successfully.

When I now rename the directory above and do the same as above again, the **make** takes 21 minutes to compile successfully. With **make V=99**, I can see that there were many more compilation steps taken compared to the case where I did not rename the top directory.

I can see that the Makefile compilation is much faster if I do not rename the top directory.

This brings me to the related question:
In Linux, will renaming or moving a directory change the times of the files in subdirectories?

I know that the Makefile does not build a target again if the modification time of the target is more recent than all its dependencies.

I was also reading about some issues with the GNU Makefile:
http://www.conifersystems.com/whitepapers/gnu-make/

Does the OpenWrt Makefile, supposed to be much more advanced than the original Linux Makefile, address some or all of these issues?

(To get the Makefile to compile faster, I also have the `openwrt/dl` as a symbolic link to a folder in my home directory, so that the user-space package tarballs don't need to be downloaded again.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't change the timestamps of contained files and directories, only on the directory itself. However, if the Makefile contains targets or dependencies that use absolute paths or even just `$(src_dir)` it will remake them, b/c it's a different/new target. See [the GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for conventions and advice on "standard" targets and variables.

However, Makefiles don't compile and there is no such thing as the original Linux Makefile. Creating/maintaining an environment like BuildRoot is very complex and the maintainers probably focus on getting it to build correctly before efficiently. If a simple patch, like adding a symlink helps to speed up the process, maybe you should send it as a suggestion for improvement upstream.

Answer (score 0):

You could run make with the jobs option, from man make:

> -j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs]
> Specifies  the  number  of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.  If there is more than one -j option, the last one is effective.  If the -j option is given without an argument, make will not limit the number of jobs that can run simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following: Really big machine with 24 threads. 128GB of ram. Build everything in `/dev/shm`. Use `make -j22` and it blazes. Just be sure to save your config since evertything disappears when you turn off the machine.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The idea of using a RAM-backed filesystem for performance boost is appealing, but you may want to add some explanation on what `/dev/mem` actually is, and what the limitations are. Also, I think the OP would not have asked the question here if simply buying a faster machine had been an option ...